# Unresolved Dependencies installing Github for Eclipse

Tags: github, eclipse-plugin

I truly do not understand this. I am trying to install the Github plugin for Eclipse from the marketplace. I've tried a variety of things but I always end up with unsatisfied dependencies of some sort.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Eclipse EGit Mylyn GitHub Feature 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
Missing requirement: Mylyn GitHub Connector UI 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui 2.2.0.201212191850-r) requires 'package org.eclipse.egit.core[2.2.0,2.3.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse EGit Mylyn GitHub Feature 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui [2.2.0.201212191850-r]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I installed EGit and Github from their respective repositories instead of using the market place. Now, when I try to create a Gist, the option is greyed out (Select snippet > right click > Github). Is there some set up that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Github integration 2.2 requires Egit 2.2, which in turn requires Eclipse 3.7.2 or higher: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365425

Chances are, your Eclipse installation is an older version than 3.7.2.